# jQuery isn't loading function on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/7pM2b/167/

This is my jQuery code:

```
    $('#change_opacity').hover(function(){
    $(this).trigger('startRumble');
    }, function(){
    $(this).trigger('stopRumble');
    });
```

What I am trying to achieve is that on hover I want the image to shake, I'm using the [jRumble](http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/) library to do this "shaking" but I can't seem to get on hover working. What am I missing?

Comment: 'trigger' is designed to trigger BUILT-IN events, not functions.

Comment: Have you initialized jrumble before calling the hover? `$('#change_opacity').jrumble();`

Comment: @Michael_B just did that now and still the same problem.

Comment: Check my answer...make sure you are wrapping everyting in `$(function(){...});` Your problem in jsFiddle was that you didn't have a link to the jRumble script included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7pM2b/175/)**

This works:

```
$(function () {
    $('#change_opacity').jrumble();

    $('#change_opacity').hover(function () {
        $(this).trigger('startRumble');
    }, function () {
        $(this).trigger('stopRumble');
    });
}
```

Comment: Your opacity is going be overridden by jRumble, you will need to modify the source to prevent it from setting opacity inline.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 'trigger' is designed to trigger BUILT-IN events, not to call functions.

I would assume you'd use something like this:

```
$('#change_opacity').hover(function(){
    startRumble(this)
}
```

Comment: Even changing it to this, it still doesn't call rumble.

Comment: I have none? I'm using the Console feature on Chrome and no errors pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize jRumble on the element?

```
$('#change_opacity').jrumble();
```

That needs to be done before you `trigger(startRumble)`.

This is according to [their site](http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/);